# How to use javascript "label" in channel entry loop?

Tags: stash, javascript

I have code that looks like

```
 <label class="city"></label>
```

that uses javascript to indicate the selected city. So when "Anchorage" for example is selected from a dropdown at the top of the page

```
 <label class="city"></label>
```

displays "Anchorage". I need to use this selected city in a channel entry loop. I've tried doing this using Stash, as in the code below, but it is not working. Is there any way to save the city in a form that can be used by Expressionengine?

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="city2" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes"}
{stash:city3}<label class="city"></label>{/stash:city3}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name="city2" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes"}
{exp:stash:parse unprefix="nested"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="place" search:city="{city3}" dynamic="no"}
{title}
<br />
{if nested:no_results}
No results
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Answer (score 0):

Channel entries tags run before the page is sent to the browser, so in order to pull this off you'll need to fetch the extra channel data from a dedicated template via AJAX.

When your JS updates the city in the DOM, simply send off an AJAX request to a new template and use URL segments to filter the output. When the response comes back you'll then need to inject it back into the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I guess it's more complicated than I hoped and I'll need to hire a developer to write the code you explained is needed. I'll come back here to confirm it worked.